# What is the Linux/X11 (and Mac OS X) equivalent to Win API SetCapture() function?

Tags: macos, winapi, mouse, x11, capture

On Windows you can "capture" the mouse to continue receiving mouse events even when it goes outside the window's client area. Here the SetCapture() documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646262(VS.85).aspx

I would like to know what is the equivalent function in Linux (X11) and Mac OS X (Cocoa).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For X: [XGrabPointer()](http://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/input/pointer-grabbing.html)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a direct Mac equivalent, but I guess you could make a transparent overlay window to grab the events.